# Modificar valores según DataGridViewComboBoxColumn generada en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: vb.net, .net, datatables, datagrid, dataset

tengo un `datagridview` que contiene una columna  `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` , la cual es generada en tiempo de ejecución e insertada a este datagridview:

```
    Public Sub GenerateCol()
        Try
            Col.DataSource = LoadData()
            Col.DisplayMember = "code"
            Col.ValueMember = "code"
            Col.Name = "col2"
            Col.HeaderText = "Column 2"
            Col.DataPropertyName = "col2"
            Col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
            dgv.Columns.Insert(15, Col)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("ERROR: " & vbCrLf & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Para cargar los datos que necesito en cada `comboboxcell`, utilizo el siguiente método:

```
Private Function LoadData() As DataTable
    Try
        dt = sd.RunService("Service", DSResult) 'ejecuta una consulta SQL
        Return dt.Tables(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("No Data" & vbCrLf & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Try
End Function
```

El método que carga los datos para los comboboxcell devuelve lo siguiente (Return):

```
code  |  date | value
---------------------
A       12/06   100
B       12/06   200
...
```

Sin embargo, como necesito cambiar dos `datagridviewnumericcolumn` según el valor que tome el `comboboxcell` por cada fila, quiero saber qué evento podría utilizar para poder realizar este cambio de valores. Una columna debe contener el valor (Value) asociado al código (Code) que toma el `comboboxcell` y la segunda columna, debo tomar ese mismo value y multiplicarlo por el valor que se encuentra en una tercera columna (cuyo valor no cambia).

Estaba pensando en implementar el `SelectedIndexChanged`, pero no estoy muy segura de ello, aunque sigo trabajando en éste evento y ver qué pasa con él (no se está desencadenando, puede que tenga algo malo):

```
Private Sub Col_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim SelectedMon As Object
    Dim SelectedDiv = CType(Col.Selected, String)

    SelectedMon = dt.Tables(0).Columns("value")
    col_Mon.Value = col_Nom * SelectedMon
    col_valmon.Value = SelectedMon

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Agregué el CellValueChanged que me indicaron más abajo, pero por alguna razón no se dispara:

```
Private Sub dgv_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)

    If dgv.SelectedRows(e.ColumnIndex).GetType.ToString() = "DataGridViewComboBoxCell" Then

        dgv.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "Value")

        Dim col_div_cell_value As Object = dt.Tables(0).Columns("value")

        dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("col_01").Value = col_div_cell_value.ToString()
        dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("col_02").Value = (col_div_cell_value * col_03)

    End If
End Sub
```

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que se entiende todo, pero para estar seguro, vos cambias el valor de un combo en alguna fila, y tenes que actualizar valores de esa misma fila?

Comment: @gbianchi Exacto, pero no debe tomar el codigo que aparece en el combobox, sino el asociado al codigo que aparece en el combobox

Comment: El selectedindexchanged del combo parece una buena idea. Porque no haces unas pruebas y nos decis con que te chocaste?

Comment: Voy a colocar lo que llevo del SelectedIndexChanged, tal vez deba corregir algo en él, debido a que no hace nada

Comment: es un datagrid de winforms?

Comment: Si, es un DataGridView

Comment: ok. no sabria como contestar la pregunta (para dejar una respuesta clara), pero en realidad estas buscando el evento CellValueChanged o CellEndEdit. Prueba con esos.

Comment: Al final me sirvió el CellValueChanged, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final pude producir el evento como corresponde; me estaba complicando de más.
Sin embargo, ahora debo arreglar el comportamiento de cada `comboboxcell`, de modo que el cambio se gatille de inmediato y no después de presionar Enter:

```
Private Sub dgv_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvBlotter.CellValueChanged
    Dim r As Integer = e.RowIndex
    Dim c As Integer = e.ColumnIndex

    Try
        If r > -1 Then 
            If c = 15 Then

                Dim flag As Double = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("col2").Value 'name of comboboxcolumn
                Dim nuevovalor As Object = flag
                Dim nominal As Double = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("col_3").Value

                dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("col_1").Value() = nuevovalor
                dgv.CurrentRow.Cells("col_2").Value() = (nuevovalor * nominal)

            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Try

End Sub
```